# How can I control which record type is selected by default when creating a new record?

Tags: record-type

When creating a new record for an object that has multiple record types, how can I control which record type is selected by default?  Is this something I was supposed to set when creating the record types? Can this be changed?

For example, I have two Opportunity record types - Service and Products.  When I click New, Service is selected by default.  Can I change that so that Products is selected by default?

I still want to be able to choose, but control what the default choice is.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, when creating record types, you can assign them to profiles and set defaults. This is usually the first place where you might want to configure this.
[image]

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_profiles_record_types.htm

If you want to do this after RecordType creation, you can set the RecordType as default in each Profile.

[image]

Comment: Got it.  so after the fact, the default record type can be set in the profile.  Thanks.